# Font color for percentage Fields in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

Hi I Have a requirment that if the the percentage is >100 then I need green else black.

So i have used the expression

```
= iif((fields!JulyRev.Value/Fields!JulyValue.Value) > 100, "SeaGreen","Black")
```

But The above is not giving any green font if the value is greater than 100 but i have infinity value which is showing as green.How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since its a percentage you would need to compare to 1 or multiply your value by 100.

```
= iif((fields!JulyRev.Value/Fields!JulyValue.Value) > 1, "SeaGreen","Black")
```

OR

```
= iif((fields!JulyRev.Value*100.0/Fields!JulyValue.Value) > 100, "SeaGreen","Black")
```